# Random variable with infinite expectation

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was trying to find $Y$,a random variable (non-negative, may be $E(|Y|)=\infty$), such that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E\Bigl(\frac{|Y|}{n^2 +|Y|}\Bigr)=\infty$$ I tried with *Cauchy* distribution but could not show it. Any kind of help/hint will be appreciated.

Comment: $P(Y=1)=1$ then Expectation is $\frac{1}{1+n^2}$ which converges.

Comment: Very sorry, read in haste, and made a foolish comment.

Comment: Motivation: $X_n$ (dependent) r.v. such that $\sum |X_n|$ converges (and so does $\sum \frac{|X_n|}{1+|X_n|}$) almost surely such that $\sum E\Bigl(\frac{|X_n|}{1+|X_n|}\Bigr)$ diverges. So I took $X_n=\frac{Y}{n^2}$

Comment: The series diverges if and only if $E(\sqrt{|Y|})$ is infinite. Note that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}E\left(\frac{|Y|}{x^2+|Y|}\right) dx\leqslant\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E\Bigl(\frac{|Y|}{n^2 +|Y|}\Bigr)\leqslant1+\int_{0}^{\infty}E\left(\frac{|Y|}{x^2+|Y|}\right)dx$$ and that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}E\left(\frac{|Y|}{x^2+|Y|}\right) dx = E(\sqrt{|Y|})\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=(\pi/2)E(\sqrt{|Y|}).$$

Comment: @did why dont you write it as an answer? dont you think that is seems ugly as a comment?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören "why dont you write it as an answer?" The OP already accepted an answer. "dont you think that is seems ugly as a comment?" Please calm down, thanks in advance.

Comment: @did just a suggestion. I mean it is the choice of OP but there may be also other people who can appreciate other answers too, I would personally)

Comment: @Did That was helpful indeed. Just to make sure I think $P(X=0)=0$ should be there.

Comment: @Robert ?? What is X in your last comment?

Comment: @Did Sorry I meant $Y$

Comment: No the condition P(Y=0)=0 is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the RV $X$ take value $n^2$ with probability $\frac{c}{n^2}$ where $c$ is a norming constant.

Then

$$E \left( \frac{X}{n^2+X} \right) \geq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{c}{k^2} \frac{k^2}{n^2+k^2} \geq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{c}{k^2} \frac{n^2}{n^2+n^2}= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{c}{k^2} \sim \frac{c}{2n} $$

which is not summable. Note that the second inequality follows from the observation that the derivative of the function

$$x \mapsto \frac{x^2}{n^2 +x^2} $$

is positive for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x > 0$.